# In jqGrid : search should start only after entering 3 characters in any field

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I want to search auto fill data after entering 3 characters in jqGrid.
for example in the field box after entering 3 characters then only it should load the data before that it should not list the data.

i tried with these options

1)searchrules:{ minValue: 3}

if i enter one character in search box it starts loading ,if i enter second then again its loading ,this is problem i am facing.
Plz help me .

Comment: Show how you implement your search. I mean show your code please.

Comment: i written code like this{name:'number', index: 'number' , width:'160', fixed:true,sortable:false, searchrules:{ minValue: 3}}">

Comment: i tried this also   {name:'number', index: 'number' , width:'160', fixed:true,sortable:false, searchrules:{custom_func: validateSearch,custom: true}}">                                                     function validateSearch(value, column) {
            alert(value)
            if ( isNaN(value) && value <= 2)
                return [false, "Please enter 3 digit value"];
            else
                return [true, ""];
        }

Comment: add your code as an edit to your post please. Also - do you understand that jqgrid use filter search only after enter key press?